# reduce dimension API in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any API in tensorflow to reduce dimension? For example, given a tensor `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]` I want to reduce its last dimension so that it becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

There is an API `tf.expand_dims()` to do the opposite. Is there a `tf.reduce_dims()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `1-D` dimensions using [`tf.squeeze`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) or you can change the shape of a tensor in  another compatible shape using [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)

In your case, since yu don't have `1-D` dimensions, you can use reshape to get what you want.

Suppose that `a` is your input tensor, you can "flatten" the input using:

```
b = tf.reshape(a, (-1,))
```

Comment: My experience that `tf.squeeze()` causes trouble by returning a Tensor with indeterminate shape.  The problem is that, with CNNs, one often does not know the exact dimension of the following layer.  I found a much better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336274/removing-dimension-using-reshape-in-keras