# Expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 256, 256, 4)

Tags: python, tensorflow, base64, image-resizing

I'm decoding a base64 image with the following code:

```py
def string_to_image(base64_string):
    decoded = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
    np_data = np.frombuffer(decoded, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(np_data, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return img
```

The goal is to receive an image from the request body, decode it, resize it with tensorflow, predict it with a model, and return a response saying what is that image:

```py
image_base64 = request.json['image']
decoded_image = string_to_image(image_base64)
image_resized = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, (256, 256))
model = load_model('src/models/mymodel.h5')
result = model.predict(np.expand_dims(image_resized/255, 0))
```

However, I'm getting the error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 256, 256, 4)`.

I don't know how to change the Shape value from '4' to '3'.

I tried the following:

```py
image_resized = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, (256, 256, 3))
```

But I get `'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width`.

I also tried:

```py
image_resized = cv2.resize(decoded_image, (256,256,3))
```

But I get `OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'`

`Overload resolution failed:`

`- Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3`

`- Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3`

Please help :(

Comment: Is it an image with RGB and alpha channel (like png with transparency channel)?. Then  you do `decoded_image[:,:,:3]` instead of resize.

Comment: I did `decoded_image[:,:,:3]` and received `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 103, 96, 3)`

Comment: what is `decoded_image.shape` ?

Comment: It is (103, 96, 4)

Comment: then you can't reshape to a bigger size. try to display and check `decoded_image` is a proper image at the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With *vijayachandran mariappan* comment and *AndreaYolo* answer I figured out a solution. First, change the channels of the image and then resize its dimensions:

```py
decoded_image = string_to_image(image_base64)
decoded_image = decoded_image[:,:,:3]
image_resized = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, (256, 256))
```

My model then was able to predict perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You could reshape the array by using `tf.squeeze` after reshaping the tensor. According to documentation, `tf.squeeze`  will remove axis with dimensions 1.

```
image_resized = tf.reshape(decoded_image, (-1, 256, 256, 3, 1))
image_resized = tf.squeeze(image_resized)
```

Comment: I've tried it, now I'm getting `Input to reshape is a tensor with 39552 values, but the requested shape has 196608 [Op:Reshape]`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete beginner. I don't have a full understanding about the topic

Comment: Hi, I forgot the None dimension that it's used for the batch size. ( I modified the original answer)
Another possible approach could be to index only the last 3 dimensions in the array: 
`image_resized = image_resized[..., :3] `

Hope it helps, and give a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336274/removing-dimension-using-reshape-in-keras

Answer (score 1):

```
resized_image = tf.image.resize(decoded_image, [256, 256])
```

The error message you encountered indicates that the size argument for resizing should be a 1-D tensor with two elements

```
'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width
```